# Pipelining an adder that sum 256, 20-bit words in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I suppose this isn't so much a Verilog question as a logic question.  I need to add up 256, 20-bit words.  This is how I implemented it for a smaller number of words, and it worked.  With the large number of words, there are timing errors.

```
module sum(clk, input_vect, out_sum);
input clk;
input [256*20-1 : 0] input_vect;
reg [25 : 0] out_sum_inter;
output reg [25 : 0] out_sum;
integer i;

always @ * 
begin
    out_sum_inter = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i = i + 1)
        out_sum_inter = out_sum_inter + input_vect[20*i - 1 -: 20];
end

always @ (posedge clk)
out_sum <= out_sum_inter;

endmodule
```

So, if not obvious, I have the combinational part split up from the sequential part.  My goal is that `out_sum` is only updated after I am sure the value of `out_sum_inter` is determined properly.

Thanks a lot.  I think I may need to pipeline this adder, but I am unsure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your synthesiser probably does automatic pipelining. If it does, you need to add enough flip-flops at the output of your adder and the synthesiser will move them back as required.

*How many is enough?* Enough to close the timing. Do some experiments.

*Why can't the synthesiser just add the right number of flip-flops?* Because synthesisers never ever change the latency through your design: they can only move flip-flops around relative to the combinational logic immediately connected to them.

Comment: I've done a lot of work on video processing applications where 'stick another pipeline stage on it' is often the answer to meeting timing